# How to merge to a revision using VisualHG

Tags: mercurial, merge, visualhg

This one should be easy, however, it has escaped me:

Is there a way to merge revisions using VisualHG?

I know I can resort to TortoiseHg, but I wanted to merge from within Visual Studio.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible - you will have to use either TortoiseHg or the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed it. I have to use TortoiseHG.